# How to insert string variable to html

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-storage

I want to add a string variable from ionic/storage to html.

home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('username') uname;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public strg: Storage) {

  }
  signIn() {
    this.strg.set('uname', this.uname.value);
    this.navCtrl.push(Page1Page);
  }
}
```

page1.html

```
<ion-content padding>
<p>Welcome to this app, /**I want to add the uname here**/ </p>
</ion-content>
```

How would I go about assigning the string from ionic/storage using the page1.ts?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fetch your username from `@ionic/storage` again like this:

**page1.ts**

```
username: string;

constructor(public strg: Storage) {
    this.username = this.strg.get('uname');
}
```

**page1.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <p>Welcome to this app, {{username}}</p>
</ion-content>
```

This `{{username}}` expression is called One-Way-Data-Binding. So every time you change
the `username` variable in your `Page1Page` class, the template `page1.html` will automatically update.

Comment: I had issues where it would remember my previous entries such as. In one
instance, I would enter '123', then in another instance, I would enter 'steve'. It would show '123'. I didn't know about navparams and I just used that and it worked. Thanks alot though.